# PHP Facebook Like button generates a token

Tags: php, facebook-like

How a person gets a code when he press a like button on facebook page.? Just watch in www.facebook.com/snapdeal

in this page we press like. it will gives us one token number.

So please tell me the referrence...

Comment: have you read the facebook api?

Comment: no clear info in facebook api so please give procedure